# Read a list of csv files by their name (another csv files has the list of names)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Could you please help me to write the python code to read a list of csv files from a folder by their names, these names are in a separate csv file. To put this in another sentence: I have a list of names of the existing files (csv),using this names can I be able to load and read those files (csv) from a folder?

`filename` is one of the `dataframe` which has the name of files as below - these files are found as csv file with these naming in the directory

```
filename = ['0RAW', '2RAW', '3RAW', '4RAW', '5RAW', '6RAW', '8RAW']
for filenames in filename: 
       pd.read_csv(filenames)
```

---

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'0RAW' does not exist: b'0RAW'`

Answer (score 0):

`.csv` is needed at the end of the file

if you don't want to include in the filename list, then include `.csv` in your code

```
filename = [ '0RAW', '2RAW', '3RAW', '4RAW', '5RAW', '6RAW', '8RAW']
for filenames in filename: 
       pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(filenames))
```

Comment: @Datanovice old habit, just switched to 3.7 a month ago

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please tell me how can I look at the each file now ? would I be able to look at a file by their name?